# How to save a time-value with EF6

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sqldatatypes

I'm creating a timesheet with ASP.Net MVC.

Therefore, I need to save date values and time values in my database.
My datafields actually are type of datetime:

```
    [Required]
    public DateTime TimesheetDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime BeginOfWork { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime EndOfWork { get; set; }
```

Now, if I'd like to save a time-value of `07:30`, the model to save contents something like: `01.01.0100 07:30:00`

With this, the saveChanges Function fails. So how can I store times in a database, so that I could calculate later with them?

Which type of data should the field have?

Thanks Carsten

Comment: Why don't you record the start and end of a period as *datetimes* rather than storing date and times separately? That would immediately let you handle e.g. people working late in the evening until the early morning without having to apply special magical rules for interpreting your data.

Comment: I would do so, but all available input-"editors". I found are so less validating, that it's a torture for the user to input the right format.
Or am I to blind to find the right input-control?
Actually I'm using ASP.Net MVC Controls of DevExpress.